# how to add value to key in json file using python

Tags: python, json, file

```
        data={}
        data['intents']=[]
        data['intents'].append({
            'tag': tag,
            'patterns': patterns,
            'response': response
        })
        with open('training.json', 'a') as training:

            json.dump(data, training)
```

I am trying to append values to the key intents. but when I am trying to append values i am getting output as follows:

```
{"intents": [{"response": "customize", "patterns": "erp", "tag": "purchase"}]}{"intents": [{"response": "kjj", "tag": "sales", "patterns": "jjkj"}]}
```

i want my output in the format given below:

```
{"intents":[
        {"tag":"sale",
         "patterns":["ptr1","ptr2"],
         "responses":["resp1","resp2"]
        },
        {"tag":"purchase",
         "patterns":["abc","def"],
         "responses":["xyz","zzz"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you care about key order?  Serialized languages aren't meant to be used for display.

Comment: actually, my concern is not about intent. I need to append values to the key indents. but when I try to do so the key gets repeated. i.e what I showed here. can you please tell me a way append key-value pair to a single key. @TheIncorrigible1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot append new data it will break your json, you have to replace data. And dont focus on indent, its not necessary
try this:

```
import json
data={}
data['intents']=[]
data['intents'].append({
    'tag': 'tag',
    'patterns': 'patterns',
    'response': 'response'
})
try:
    with open('training.json', 'r') as training:
        old_data = training.readlines()
        if old_data:
            old_data = json.loads(old_data[0])
            for intents in data['intents']:
                old_data['intents'].append(intents)
            data = old_data
            old_data = None
    with open('training.json', 'w') as training:
        json.dump(data, training)
except:
    with open('training.json', 'w') as training:
        json.dump(data, training)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to append an item to a list in the object (and not append text to the `json` file itself), you need to first read the `json`, then append and write:

```
import os

data = {'intents': []}
if os.path.exists('training.json'):
    with open('training.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

data['intents'].append({
            'tag': tag,
            'patterns': patterns,
            'response': response
})

with open('training.json', 'w') as training:
    json.dump(data, training)
```

Comment: actually, my concern is not about intent. I need to append values to the key indents.
but when I try to do so the key gets repeated. i.e what I showed here.
can you please tell me a way append key-value pair to a single key.

Comment: neha check my answer, you will get your desired output

Answer (score 0):

Well you can add it without copying the contents from old JSOF file easily.

```
    import json

    data={}
    data['intents']=[]
    data['intents'].append({
        'tag': 'tag',
        'patterns': 'patterns',
        'responses': 'responses'
    })

    tag = request.json['tag']
    new_response = request.json['response']
    for intent in intents['intents']:
        if intent['tag'] in tag:
            if new_response in intent['responses']:
                response = {"success":False,"message":"Response already found in the training data"}
                return response
            else:
                
                print("updating file")
                intent['responses'].append(new_response)
                data = intents
                with open('intents.json', 'w') as training:
                    json.dump(data, training)
```

This will append the new response under the same tag. Also if the same response is present in it, then it will skip.